# Implementing "Show More" in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement "Show More" feature for my comment section in Reactjs but when I click show more it doesn't load the whole array however it removes the show more link. Here is my code:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
return {limit:3 ,showMore:false};
},
showMore:function() {
  this.setState({showMore: true, limit: this.props.comments.length});
},
render: function() {
  var cls=[];
  var length=this.props.comments.length;

  if(length >= this.state.limit){
      cls=[];
      for (var i=0;i<this.state.limit;i++ )
          cls.push(this.props.comments[i]);
  }
      return (
    <div className="commentBox">
        <CommentList data={cls} />

        {length> 3 &&!this.state.showMore? <div><a onClick={this.showMore}  >show more</a></div>: null}
    </div>
);
 }
});
```

making any change to state.comments doesn't affect the view at all.

Comment: You probably know already that one should not copy props into state. As this usually leads to disaster. I would propose to keep only the number of visible items in the state. Set it to 3 by default and on click on showMore you increase the number of visible items.

Comment: @pintxo I did what you suggested but it still doesn't change the view [you can see the edit in my code]. I have to mention that this is like a newsfeed and there are many <CommentBox> elements each with a unique key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: http://jsbin.com/ceqisepewu/edit?js,console,output

Compare it with your solution and find the reason it did not work.

Comment: I did exactly what you have here. Initally cls has 3 elements. when I click on show more it changes the cls to 6 elements but it doesn't update the view. I feel like because I have a list of <commentbox> in my newsfeed it doesn't update it. Can it be that?

Comment: nvm it is fixed! I changed this.state to this.props in the child element of <commentBox> thanks for the help